# "java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String" with a not empty String

Tags: java, parsing, exception, double

I am currently working on a personal project  outside of class and am running into some issues while reading in a text file into a linked list. When reading in the first double I get a

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

error. I added a print line into the program to print out what I am trying to parse into a double and the variable is in fact, not empty, and is in fact a double.

Like I said above, I added a print line to print out the string I am trying to parse into a double and it seems to be okay. Here is the String that is read in and split into the array I am printing from:

```
500.0 % 04/05/2019 % This is paycheck 1 % true % 49.5
```

I have to parse two strings into doubles and I only run into problems with the first one. When I comment out the first double being parsed, the program runs with no problems. Here is the full output from running to program

```
 *File loading*


    *500.0*

    *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String*
        *at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)*
        *at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)*
        *at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)*
        *at fileHandling.readPaycheck(fileHandling.java:194)*
        *at UserMenu.main(UserMenu.java:20)*
```

The problems happens in the "Splitting the array into its appropriate temp variables" section in this line of code:

```
payCheckAmount = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);
```

Here is the code for the method this is in

```
public void readPaycheck(LinkedList<PayCheck> paycheck) throws IOException {

        // Declare Variables
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(payChecks); // Scanner used to read in from the payChecks text file
        String temp; // A string used to hold the data read in from the file temporarily
        String[] tempArray; // A String array used to temporarily hold data from the text file
        double payCheckAmount; // A double holding the amount of the paycheck
        String paycheckDate; // A string holding the date of the paycheck
        String description; // A string holding a description of the paycheck
        boolean payCheckSplit; // A boolean stating if the paycheck has been split or not
        double amountUnSplit; // A double

        // A while loop that runs while the text file still has data in it
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            // Reading in a new line from the paycheck file
            temp = sc.nextLine();
            // Splitting the line into an array
            tempArray = temp.split(" % ");

            // Temp output used for testing of the issue at hand
            System.out.println(tempArray[0]);

            // Splitting the array into its appropriate temp variables
            payCheckAmount = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);
            paycheckDate = tempArray[1];
            description = tempArray[2];
            payCheckSplit = Boolean.parseBoolean(tempArray[3]);
            amountUnSplit = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[4]);

            // putting the temp variables into a temp paycheck object
            PayCheck tempCheck = new PayCheck(payCheckAmount, paycheckDate, description, payCheckSplit, amountUnSplit);
            paycheck.add(tempCheck);

        }

    }
```

**Edit:**

Here is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the problem I am running into:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Declare Variables
        File payChecks = new File("C:\\Users\\zwtw\\Documents\\paychecks.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(payChecks); 

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

            String temp = sc.nextLine();

            String[] tempArray = temp.split(" % ");

            System.out.println(tempArray[0]);

            // Splitting the array into its appropriate temp variables
            double payCheckAmount = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);
            String paycheckDate = tempArray[1];
            String description = tempArray[2];
            boolean payCheckSplit = Boolean.parseBoolean(tempArray[3]);
            double amountUnSplit = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[4]);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of the text file mentioned in the code above:

```
500.0 % 04/05/2019 % This is paycheck 1 % true % 49.5
450.0 % 04/09/2019 % This is paycheck 2 % true % 49.75
```

Comment: Try to also print the content of `tempArray[4]` .

Comment: @Arnaud7 I tried printing the variable tempArray[4] and it printed out as 49.5 as it should have. I also printed out amountUnSplit and it prints without issue

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown at the line `amountUnSplit = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[4]);` instead of some other line?

Comment: @Sweeper The error that is given to me says it is happening on line 194 of the file which corresponds to this line of code: <payCheckAmount = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);>. After commenting that line out I no longer get the error

Comment: I can't reproduce this exception. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Sweeper I am unable to post the code directly in the comment, It is too long, how should I go about doing it?

Here is a link to the code, whats in the text file, and the error:

Comment: @ChaseGeis you can [edit] your question. Also, keep it to a few dozen lines, otherwise it’s not “minimal”.

Comment: Your code works for me

Comment: @Sweeper I have come to find it has something to do with my while loop. In the minimal example I added it rusn fine. The second I add the while loop back in though it starts throwing the error again

Comment: My guess is that your text file contains an empty line at the end. Try printing something at the start of the whole loop. Does it get printed 3 times instead of 2? Try adding a check at the start of the while loop to see if `temp` is an empty string.

Comment: @Sweeper I implemented a counter that prints every time the loop starts and ends and it is only getting through 1 full loop and getting an error thrown on the second. After adding something that checks if temp is empty or null and end the method if it is, the error is not being thrown anymore, but is getting kicked out of the method meaning that temp is not reading in the second line of text from the file. I also checked, there are no empty lines in the text document.

Comment: Instead of ending the method there, try doing `continue;` when the line is empty. How does it behave now?

Comment: I don't have java installed on my machine, but i tried running the minimal example online by changing scanner to read from `System.in`. The only way I could reproduce the problem was by adding an empty line to the end. Try checking that `tempArray.length == 5` before performing any of the conversions.

Comment: @Sweeper Holy crap. Thank you so much for planting this seed in my brain. The continue worked. This made me think about how I was writing the data to the file. I was adding new lines to the strings being writing in a different method of my code. I reworked how the data was being written and it works now in my actual code. **THANK YOU SO MUCH!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text file likely contains empty lines. You can either remove the new lines in the text file, change how the text file is created, or just skip the empty lines when you read it.

This is how you skip the empty lines:

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

        String temp = sc.nextLine();

        if (temp.equals("")) { continue; } // <--- notice this line
        String[] tempArray = temp.split(" % ");

        System.out.println(tempArray[0]);

        // Splitting the array into its appropriate temp variables
        double payCheckAmount = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[0]);
        String paycheckDate = tempArray[1];
        String description = tempArray[2];
        boolean payCheckSplit = Boolean.parseBoolean(tempArray[3]);
        double amountUnSplit = Double.parseDouble(tempArray[4]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! If I would have been using a different text editor other than Notepad on Windows I would have caught the error sooner